# How do I authenticate/validate an Android app on an App Engine Server with OAuth 2?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication, servlets, oauth-2.0

I have a simple application that lets a user draw pictures. There are Android, IOS, and web-based versions. I also let users store their pictures on our App-engine servers and I want them to be able to collaborate with other users. I want to use Google accounts for authentication and the basis of some permission scheme.

I do not know how to validate/authenticate a user’s Google account on android (or IOS). I am hoping somebody can help or point me in the right direction. Here is what I understand so far:

On the Web-based client, I just use Google-web toolkits UserService. However for my app-engine servlets i'm not sure what I should use. Currently the servlets have code like this:

```
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException, ServletException
{
    OAuthService oauth = null; 
    oauth = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService(); 
    User user = oauth.getCurrentUser();
    // Do stuff
}
```

In my android application I think I'm supposed to do something like:

1)  Get the Account from the AccountManager

2)  Call:

```
accountManager.getAuthToken
(account,  // Account 
"oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",//AUTH Token Type
null,   // Options
this,  // Activity
new MyAccountsManagerCallBack(),  // call-back
null);    // Handler
```

This will give me authorization token.

3)  ?? profit ??

This is where I am lost. Do I send this authorization token as a clear-text query parameter to my app-engine server, then make a request from the web server to the userinfo/profile api? That doesn’t seem secure.

Is there some way to make the pervious code with OAuthService work?

The samples for OAuth 2 use the Google task API, however I want to use my app-engine API. I’ve found information for OAuth 1 using cookies, webviews, title, etc, but nothing on OAuth 2, and none of them really tell me how to validate server side.

I really have no clue what I should be doing here. I would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, this is an example of my java servlet served on app engine:

```
public class ServletSecureData extends HttpServlet { 
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    UserService usersrvc = null;      
    usersrvc = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    User user = usersrvc.getCurrentUser();
    if(user == null)
      throw new IOException();

    Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int num = r.nextInt(10);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.printf("Security !! %s radioactive man! %d", user.getEmail(), num);
    out.close();
  }
}
```

This servlet was protected with a security constraint defined in the web.xml file. I wanted to be able to access this servlet using an android client. I thought that I had to used Oauth but it turned out I needed to use an older deprecated service ClientLogin

I based my implementation off the code from this site: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app